# Change html background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, properties, background

I need change the background image, so I using:

```
$('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/wallpaper/'+wp+'.jpg)'});
```

But, I need use the properties: no-repeat fixed bottom left

If I try:

```
$('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/wallpaper/'+wp+'.jpg)  no-repeat fixed bottom left'});
```

Its not work. someone can solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('body').css({background : 'url(images/wallpaper/'+wp+'.jpg)  no-repeat fixed bottom left'});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('body').css({background : 'url(images/wallpaper/'+wp+'.jpg)  no-repeat fixed bottom left'});`

It's just like the CSS property of the same name.

`background` is a shortcut to setting `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-attachment`, `background-position` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change `backgroundImage` to `background`.

Answer (score 0):

$('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(images/wallpaper/'+wp+'.jpg)', backgroundRepeat : 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition : 'fixed 0 100%'});